# Toggle on/off either to off/on another

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle, togglebutton

I have two toggle buttons, I want both buttons to work in opposite for each other in such a way:

When I toggle on/green **First Toggle**, **Second Toggle** should be turned off and vice versa (when Second Toggle is on/green, First Toggle should be off/red)

```css
div.switcher label {
    padding: 0;
}
div.switcher label input {
    display: none;
}
div.switcher label * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input:checked {
    background-color: #46c146;
    gap: 10px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 54%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 3px double red;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.switcher label input:checked+span {
    background: green;
    border-color: green;
}
div.switcher label input+span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 26px;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.switcher label input:checked+span small {
    left: 50%;
}
div.switcher label input+span small {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<label>First Toggle</label>
<div class="switcher">
  <label for="toggle-1">
    <input id="toggle-1" class="my_features" type="checkbox">
      <span>
        <small></small>
      </span>
    <small></small>
  </label>
</div>

<label>Second Toggle</label>
<div class="switcher">
  <label for="toggle-2">
    <input id="toggle-2" class="my_features" type="checkbox">
      <span>
        <small></small>
      </span>
    <small></small>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum interdum vehicula tristique. Vestibulum et est sem. Ut venenatis sagittis gravida. Nam enim tortor, lacinia pretium dolor sit amet, rutrum ultricies ligula. Nunc lacinia metus in sagittis accumsan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery, here is the function when either is on another will be off.

```js
var allIds = [ "toggle-1", "toggle-2" ];
function uncheck( event ) 
{
   var id = event.target.id;
   allIds.forEach( function( id ){
      if ( id != event.target.id )
      {
         document.getElementById( id ).checked = false;
      }
   });
}

jQuery("#toggle-1").click(uncheck);
jQuery("#toggle-2").click(uncheck);
```

```css
div.switcher label {
    padding: 0;
}
div.switcher label input {
    display: none;
}
div.switcher label * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input:checked {
    background-color: #46c146;
    gap: 10px;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 54%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 3px double red;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.switcher label input:checked+span {
    background: green;
    border-color: green;
}
div.switcher label input+span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 26px;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.switcher label input:checked+span small {
    left: 50%;
}
div.switcher label input+span small {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>First Toggle</label>
<div class="switcher">
  <label for="toggle-1">
    <input id="toggle-1" class="my_features" type="checkbox">
      <span>
        <small></small>
      </span>
    <small></small>
  </label>
</div>

<label>Second Toggle</label>
<div class="switcher">
  <label for="toggle-2">
    <input id="toggle-2" class="my_features" type="checkbox">
      <span>
        <small></small>
      </span>
    <small></small>
  </label>
</div>
```